# Var index of a class

Tags: javascript, class, indexing

I have the the following var

```
a = 1
```

How can I use this to target the index of a class. Something like this

```
$('.timeLeft'[a]).click ...
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can:

```
$('.timeLeft').eq(a).click
```

(This is zero based)